# cocoa access to PHContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL?

Tags: macos, cocoa, photokit

The official [Apple documentation for PHContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcontenteditinginput/1518671-fullsizeimageurl) says this is available in macOS 10.11+, however Xcode doesn't think so. Curiously [Step 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcontenteditinginput) to get the  PHContentEditingInput is via the [requestContentEditingInput method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624061-requestcontenteditinginput) which the documentation says tvOS and iOS only.

Is there a way to get PHContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL for a PHAsset on macOS?